# Limits involving complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose we want to evaluate $$\lim_{z\to -i} \frac{z^2-1}{z+i},$$ where $z$ is a complex variable. I can't quite see what to do here. Thoughts/ hints?

Comment: Is there a typo, or have you overlooked the fact the limit is not of the form $0/0$?

Comment: You could factor the polynomials thanks to the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: Someone edited my problem. The numerator should read $z^2-1$.

Comment: The resulting limit is still of the form $a/0$, where $a\ne0$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am stuck on this. Even wolfram alpha cannot find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{z\to -i} \frac{z^2-1}{z+i}=\lim_{z\to 0} \frac{z^2-2iz-2}{z}=\lim_{z\to 0} z-2i-\frac{2}{z}=-2i-2\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{z}$$

But $\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1}{z}$ is not defined indeed if $z$ approach $0$ along the postive real axis the limit will be $+\infty$ but if $z$ approach $0$ along the negative real axis the limit will be $-\infty$.

So $\lim_{z\to -i} \frac{z^2-1}{z+i}$ is not defined.